# I want to prevent spam on Mongodb Function Endpoint

Tags: mongodb

I'm really new to this and I have created a MongoDB Function

```
exports = function(payload, response) {
  const answernum = payload.query.answer || "";
  
  const collection = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas")
  .db("answers")
  .collection("answers_records")
  .findOne({answer:answernum});
  
  return collection;
};
```

I want to limit request traffic to prevent too many requests.
Thanks.

Comment: What result do you expect? Please clarify

Comment: I have an endpoint example https://somth/endpoint now id wants users to spam requests on this if they do, I want to prompt a message like too many requests.

Comment: Too broad to answer. Are you looking for something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

Comment: I tried using it gives me an error also it's a MongoDB atlas function